# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://peerplays-dev.blocktrades.info/ws/

Tags: websocket, mozilla, node-modules

I am trying to run graphene-ui app in mozilla 50.0 version but I am unable to establish a connection with the websocket, I have initialized the flag as well in mozilla and searched a lot every where at once I got this [link](http://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/how-to-enable-websocket-on-firefox/).

This link has provided me a way to make network.websocket.enabled and network.websocket.override-security-block preferences to true by reaching in about:config settings but I cannot find any such flags in mozilla 50.0 version.
So, please provide me with the way so that I can establish a connection with the websocket.

Comment: Your link refers to Firefox 4 (!!!), and it's too hold to be still relevant in the Firefox 50 era. Please update your question with the output or error you're seeing from the web console.